# Перенос неподходящего по параметрам строки числа в другую строку

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый вечер!

Может ли кто-нибудь помочь с таким [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/oneng/j3c8zpvx/embedded/result/).

Задача в том, чтобы сделать проверку и перекопипастить введенное число, если оно не подходит по тем параметрам в товаре. Например, в товаре в строку, где разрешено вводить числа только от 6 до 16, ввели 22, тогда число должно с текущей строки переместится в ту строку, где параметры позволяют это (ну, там, где, допустим, от 17 до 26).

В примере, думаю, понятней, но там в основном верстка. ((

Заранее благодарен!

[**sameDEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/oneng/j3c8zpvx/embedded/result/)

Comment: Актуально?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не очень понял тз, но как-то так ( http://jsfiddle.net/bqv77dgm/ ):

```
var $checkInp = $('.on-check');

$checkInp.change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var thisVal = $this.val();
    var noResult = true;
    $.each($checkInp,function(ind,elm){
        var $elm = $(elm);
        var minVal = $elm.data('min');
        var maxVal = $elm.data('max');
        if ((thisVal>=minVal) && (thisVal<=maxVal)) {      
            $this.val('');
            $elm.val(thisVal);
            noResult = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (noResult) {
        alert('wrong');
    }
});
```

Comment: Воу! Почти то, что нужно, вы даже лучше сделали, атрибуты использовав,
единственное: у последнего инпута в товаре есть только одно ограничение - это атрибут "data-min", а атрибут "data-max" у последнего инпута товара вообще неограничен. Скорее всего для "неограничения" там будет стоять ноль.

Comment: Не указывайте тогда data-max, а код примените следующий: `var maxVal = $elm.data('max') || thisVal; `, вот тут пример: http://jsfiddle.net/bqv77dgm/2/

Comment: Спасибо Олег, это то, чего не хватало!)